# R: POST request with JSON Parameters

Tags: json, r, httr

I am not new to R but I am new to using httr. I have REST API call that I need to make and POST some parameters. But I have been unable to get that working. It looks like my API doesn't find the parameters and returns a default data set instead. I am using:

```
url = "http://myapi"

r <- POST(url, body = "{'start':'2016-07-01T17:01:46-07:00','end'='2016-08-02T16:59:00-07:00'}", encode="json", verbose())
```

The verbose setting is showing me the string as it should be in JSON but my API can't seem to find it. I have also tried:

```
r <- POST(url, body = list(start="2016-01-01T17:01:46-07:00",end="2016-08-02T16:59:00-07:00"), encode="json", verbose())
```

But this version formats the JSON incorrectly and puts brackets around my parameter values.

**Note** that I am using the same API with the same parameters in a Python script, so I know for a fact that the API and parameter formatting is correct. It's just the posting side within the R code that doesn't seem to work quite right.

Comment: are you able to add the actual API you're trying to call?

Comment: @SymbolixAU I'd prefer not to

Comment: What does "my API can't seem to find it" mean exactly? How does the `verbose()` output compare to your Python request? I find if you point both your R and Python code to a site like [requestbin](https://requestb.in/) you can compare the HTTP messages. That will at least help us tell what the difference is otherwise we have no idea what the "right" format is.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the requestbin suggestion. I'm working there now and tracking down this issue